# How to get last inserted id, then assign it to a global variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I want to get last inserted id, and then assign it to a global variable to use it later.

I'm use `callback_after_insert` as the following:

```
$crud->callback_after_insert(array($this, '_callback_get_lastInsertID'));

function _callback_get_lastInsertID($post_array,$primary_key) {
   $this->lastInsertedId = $primary_key;
}
```

Then, when use the `$this->lastInsertedId` to get its value, but I do not find any value ​​stored.

```
function featured_ad_offer() { 
    echo $this->lastInsertedId; 
    @$data['content'] .= $this->load->view('featured_ad_offer', '', true); 
    $this->load->view('index', $data); 
}
```

There is an error message say `Undefined property: Content::$lastInsertedId`

Now, how to do that ?

Comment: A bit more information regarding your use of $this would help. Are you in the same object? Are you sure it gets set in the first place?

Comment: `Are you in the same object?` -> yes.  `Are you sure it gets set in the first place ?` -> yes.

Comment: If it gets set, then at what point does it become unset? immediately after the function exit?

Comment: I'm Sorry, but I don't understand, but I'm use this variable in another method in same object.    
`public function featured_ad_offer() {
echo $this->lastInsertedId ; @$data['content'] .= $this->load->view('featured_ad_offer', '', true); $this->load->view('index', $data);
}`

Comment: You should update your OP instead of copying such a large chunk of code into the comment. If your variable is available at one point, but then not available later then something is re-setting that variable, or you're accessing a wrong object.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [declaring](http://www.php.net/public) your variable in class (assuming both functions are in the same class) right after "declaring" class itself i.e.

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
    private $lastInsertedId = NULL;

    public function fcn1() {$this->lastInsertedId = 3.14;}
    public function fcn2() {var_dump($this->lastIndertedId);}

}
```

If you really mean using it as `global variable` you need to declare it in `CI_Controller`, or better yet create file in `/core/Public_Controller` that extends `CI_Controller` and let all your controllers be extended not by `CI_Controller` but `Public_Controller` therefore you can easily declare variables that are "global".

For more information on extending use this [tutorial by Phil](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY).

If you have troubles here is a [user guide link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html).

There is another option (not recommended!) [config class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html),

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value'); //setting a config value
$this->config->item('item name'); //accesing config value
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this to get the last inserted id

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

store it in the session

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this>session->set_userdata('last_inserted_id');
```

and use this session variable in other places

```
$last_inserted_id = $this->session->userdata('last_inserted_id');
```

wish this help :D

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you need it can easily be resolved with Codeigniter sessions. So for example, what you can do is:

```
$crud->callback_after_insert(array($this, '_callback_get_lastInsertID'));

function _callback_get_lastInsertID($post_array,$primary_key) {
   $this->session->set_userdata('last_insert_id', $primary_key);
}
```

Make sure that you have [session class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) loaded first. The best way to do it is to actually have the sessions library at the autoload.

Now to actually call the last_insert_id again, you can simply do it by calling:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('last_insert_id');
```

So in your example you can simple do:

```
function featured_ad_offer() { 
    echo $this->session->userdata('last_insert_id'); 
    @$data['content'] .= $this->load->view('featured_ad_offer', '', true); 
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
```

}